# How can I test my homebrew Nintendo Entertainment System software on real hardware?

Tags: hardware, homebrew, nintendo, 6502

A few years ago, I implemented an NES game as a class project, written in 6502 assembly. I only ever ran it on an NES emulator, but I would like to see it run on the real hardware. Is there any development board to do this? I understand it is somewhat tricky, with mapper chips and such, but I am willing to limit to just a common mapper (say MMC3).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would check out [RetroZone](http://www.retrousb.com/), especially the page with [Developer Tools](http://www.retrousb.com/index.php?cPath=24&osCsid=f87d0805e3dc04c13991392e6853f8de) for the NES and SNES. They have a [device](http://www.retrousb.com/product_info.php?cPath=24&products_id=36) that you can install into an NES to flash carts (like [this one)](http://www.retrousb.com/product_info.php?cPath=24&products_id=35) or a [cart](http://www.retrousb.com/product_info.php?cPath=24&products_id=34) that will read ROMs off of a CF card.

Comment: Very old question, but whoever stumbles over this in search of NES related information should head to http://nesdev.parodius.com which is the best resource for that.

Comment: Now that Parodius Networking has shut down, the site was moved to http://nesdev.com/ which has an active forum and wiki.